# Postfix pipe fails with "Command output: Could not open input file: example@yahoo.com"

Tags: php, pipe, postfix-mta

I have been searching the interwebs for 3-4 hours today with no luck so guys, I'd appreciate some help.

I set up a Postfix pipe to a PHP file and while checking /var/log/maillog it looks like the pipe wants to work but I get this error:

```
Aug  7 20:23:15 u18320568 postfix/pipe[23495]: 483F023D88: to=<email_route@localhost.localdomain>, relay=email_route, delay=0.16, delays=0.07/0.01/0/0.07, dsn=5.3.0, status=bounced (Command died with status 1: "/var/www/vhosts/example.com/dev.example.com/library/parse.php". Command output: Could not open input file: example@yahoo.com )
```

And this is what my parse.php looks like

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?php

$f = fopen("php://stdin", "r")
mail('me@gmail.com','Reasons','This: <br><br>'.$f)

?>
```

I tried removing the -q from the top line (and verified PHP is actually there) and I get:

```
Aug  7 20:20:27 u18320568 postfix/pipe[22971]: 5673C23D84: to=<email_route@localhost.localdomain>, relay=email_route, delay=0.1, delays=0.07/0/0/0.03, dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (temporary failure. Command output: pipe: fatal: pipe_command: execvp /var/www/vhosts/example.com/dev.example.com/library/parse.php: No such file or directory )
```

Looking for ideas, anyone?

Comment: The cold wind blows... Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, turns out it was that the code was done in Notepad++ (and I guess not in a unix editor). I had to use dos2unix to get it to convert correctly and now the file executes nicely with

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
```

I found my answer here
https://askubuntu.com/questions/239927/usr-bin-php-sometimes-not-working-on-12-10-server

Comment: hmm. So the syntax errors in the code above also went away?